# JavaScript Regex for overwriting file path

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp

I want to replace file path with gulp task. For that I need to write a Regex:

I have a folder structure `../assets/js/components/main/main.component.html`, where I need to replace the whole path, `../assets/js/components/**/`, with an empty string. So after applying a Regex on my example I should get only the html file, e.g.: `main.component.html`

The Regex should match only the path `../assets/js/components/` with only one level of subfolder, e.g.: `../assets/js/components/**/`. Path with only `../assets/js/components/` should not match and path with more than one subfolder neither `../assets/js/components/main/shouldnotmatch/`

I wrote already one Regex:

[`^..\/assets\/js\/components\/(?:\[^\/\]+\/?)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/gO4eS8/93)

The problem here is, that It selects everything. Any idea how to fix this?

**EDIT:**

More examples:

`../assets/js/components/main/ => ../assets/js/components/main/
../assets/js/components/ => should not match
../assets/js/components/test/index.html => ../assets/js/components/test/
../assets/js/components/main/shouldnotmatch/shouldnotmatch.html =>  ../assets/js/components/main/
../assets/js/components/some_components.html => should not match
../assets/js/components/1.html => should not match`

Comment: First, you will have to escape `.`

Comment: Note that you may use `^\.\.\/assets\/js\/components\/([^\/]+\/?)$` and make sure you refer to the Group 1 value inside the code. Note that in your demo, you must put `\n` into `[^\/]` to avoid matching across lines. See https://regex101.com/r/PbCnXa/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, but then it selects only the first one. It should select `../assets/js/components/**/` everywhere.

Comment: @Gabriel Sorry, should it match `shouldnotmatch.html`? Now, it becomes rather unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, no, there also should match only the path `../assets/js/components/**/`

Comment: [It does, doesn't it](https://regex101.com/r/gO4eS8/95)?

Comment: No, it should match path `../assets/js/components/` with one subfolder

Comment: But you say `../assets/js/components/main/shouldnotmatch.html` should not be matched. Look, DNKROZ posted my suggestion as an answer.

Comment: I've edited the post and added a few examples.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's a little different at the start

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually it matches the same from the examples given

Comment: @DNKROZ You just made two mistakes :) Gabriel, check https://regex101.com/r/gO4eS8/97. Or maybe even https://regex101.com/r/6c9Bfu/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My bad you are correct!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is what I need https://regex101.com/r/6c9Bfu/1, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to avoid matching HMTL/HTM files when used at the location of `subfolder`.

You may use a lookahead to add that restriction and use

```
^\.\.\/assets\/js\/components\/(?![^\/]+\.html?$)[^\/]+\/?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6c9Bfu/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\.\.` - 2 dots
- `\/assets\/js\/components\/` - a literal string `/assets/js/components/`
- `(?![^\/]+\.html?$)` - immediately to the left of the current location, there can't be:

  - `[^\/]+` - 1 or more chars other than `/`
  - `\.html?` -  `.html` or `htm`
  - `$` - at the end of the string
- `[^\/]+` - 1 or more chars other than `/`
- `\/?` - 1 or 0 `/`s